# Conditional extends in Blade

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

Is there any way to do a conditional `@extends` statement in the Blade templating language?

### What I've tried:

```
@if(!Request::ajax())
    @extends('dashboard.master')
    @section('content')
@endif

<div class="jumbotron">
    Hey!
</div>

@if(!Request::ajax())
    @stop
@endif
```

### Output

When the request was not AJAX it printed out `@extends('dashboard.master')`, but the AJAX request worked fine.

### What I'm trying to do

Stop including the master template (which includes `header` and `footer`) for AJAX so it can easily display the requested content

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in the master layout:

```
   @if(!Request::ajax())

       //the master layout with @yield('content'). i.e. your current layout

   @else

       @yield('content')

   @endif
```

Comment: i don't see it as hacky. it is simple control. if `request` is ajax, then show this. if `request` is not ajax, then show that. plain and simple. Also keeps your code clean.

Answer (score 73):

```
@extends((( Request::ajax()) ? 'layouts.ajax' : 'layouts.default' ))
```

Comment: Nice for clean simplicity

Comment: this is what works! thanks. I completely forgot about ternary statements.

Comment: I know that is a old topic, but the @section could be resolved by adding a **@yield('content')** in the **layouts.ajax**. I did that and works fine.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of logic should really be kept out of the template.

In your controller set the `$layout` property to be dashboard.master then instead of calling returning your view or response, terminate with just `$this->layout->content = View::make('dashboard.template')`

Take a look at the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#controller-layouts) on this

You could end up with something like this

```
<?php

class Something extends BaseController {

    $layout = 'dashboard.master';

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $template = View::make('dashboard.template');

        if(Request::ajax()) {
            return $template;
        }

        $this->layout->content = $template;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot get `$this->layout->content` to display any content for some reason.

Comment: You may need use `@yield('content')` in your master file [Controller](https://github.com/Lavoaster/BeardCMS/blob/master/app/controllers/PageController.php) [Template](https://github.com/Lavoaster/BeardCMS/blob/master/app/views/layouts/master.blade.php#L62)

Comment: My master already has an `@yield` in there, http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SDXs1kx3

Comment: Also is there really a point in having the header and footer in separate files?

Comment: Well that comment derped, you do have the 
`/**
* Setup the layout used by the controller.
*
* @return void
*/
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }` 

in your BaseController, right?

Comment: Yes, that's my whole `BaseController` file. It displays whatever is in `$this->layout`, but not `$this->layout->content`.

Comment: Just checking if this is L4 or L3?

Comment: Laravel 4, I started the project yesterday morning.

Comment: In your method, does var_dump()'ing the $this->layout variable show anything?

Comment: This does work but it wasn't made that clear (but I see it now) that `$this->layout->content` is set to a variable, not a section. The accepted answer is simpler in my opinion, though. Upvote for you.

Comment: It may be simpler, but IMO if you think like this you will end up refactoring it back to the controller at a later time should you need to output content regardless of the page being requested by ajax. But thanks anyway. :)