# Multiple layouts extending following conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to extend a layout for the following user type.
For example, if the user is an "administrateur" he will get a different layout. I have three types of users, and I tried this in my view for two types, but it's not working.

```php
@if($user->type === 'professeur')
    @extends('layouts.dashprof')
@elseif($user->type === 'admin')
    @extends('layouts.dash')
@endif
```

I get the variable `$user` with my view.

```php
public function profile()
{
    return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it works for me

```
@extends(Auth::user()->type === 'professeur' ? 'layouts.dashprof' : 'layouts.dash' )
```

> I don't know why this works but not the `@if` block. May be because it
>   is used outside the `@extends`, some expert might help on this.

You can also do multiple conditions by nesting them:

```
@extends(Auth::user()->type === 'professeur' ? 'layouts.dashprof' : ( Auth::user()->type === 'student'? 'layouts.student ': 'layouts.dash' ) );
```

Comment: please what should i change if i have 3 type of users?

Answer (score 0):

```
@if($user->type == "professeur")
    @extends('layouts.dashprof')
@elseif($user->type == "admin")
    @extends('layouts.dash')
@endif
```

Make sure you use the `==` operator to compare values. A single `=` is trying to assign a value.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer I tryed this before it's not working

Comment: Before you if block, try adding `{{ dump($user->type) }}` to see if the property is outputting what you expect.

Comment: yes it's giving me the data I want but  it's like the condition is not working I have a repitition in the page I can avoid all this problems using the controller but im just looking in case we can do something like that to avoid multiple views

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19691608/1342183 might give some better insight into this problem

Comment: FunkyMonk91 thank you I followed  @Aditya Thakur solution it's working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@if(Auth::user()->type === 'professeur')
    @extends('layouts.dashprof')
@elseif(Auth::user()->type === 'admin')
    @extends('layouts.dash')
@endif
```

and you don't need to return a user object to your view.

Answer (score 0):

You are going against MVC. Views are for rendering. You should put this logic inside the profile() method like so:

In your controller:

```
    $layout='Your-default-layout';
    if($user->type === 'professeur'){
        $layout='layouts.dashprof';
    }elseif($user->type === 'admin'){
        $layout='layouts.dash';
    }
return view('profile',compact('layout'));
```

Then in your view:

```
    @extends($layout)
```

Also please note that you do not need to return "**Auth::user()**" from your controller. You may simply call it from anywhere within your views.