# how can i include an extend a layout file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.2, laravel-6.2

I am having difficulty extending to different layout file according to the if else condition

```
@if($subdomain_alias === "blk")
    @extends("layouts.frontend-new")
    @section('title')
    Home
    @endsection
    @section('content')
    {{-- Some Content  --}}
    @endsection
@else
    @extends('layouts.frontend')
    @section('title')
    Home
    @endsection
    @section('content')
    {{-- Some Content  --}}
    @endsection
@endif
```

But the problem is both the layout is included and i can see everything twice.

i tried using @include but the view contents are not loaded in that.
[image]

you can see the header twice.

can someone please help me??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional extends in Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524365/conditional-extends-in-blade)

Comment: No, i want to include different  layout files with different content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a ternary operator for selecting between different master layout in first line of your blade file:

```
@extends(($subdomain_alias === "blk" ? "layouts.frontend-new" : "layouts.frontend"))

@section('title')
Home
@endsection

@section('content')
{{-- Some Content  --}}
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, i just separated the condition from the layout.

`@extends((( $subdomain_alias === "blk") ? 'layouts.frontend-new' : 'layouts.frontend' ))`

used this for including the different layout and separate if else for the sections.